# How do you map immutable nested objects with ObjectMapper?

Tags: swift, objectmapper

I'm testing the immutable mapping in ObjectMapper (for Swift) and I can't get any immutable objects to map. For example, if I have `let foo: Foo` then later I have:

```
public init(map: Map) throws {
    foo = try map.value("some_foo")
}
```

I get nothing in my `foo` variable. Mapping works fine with primitive objects like Int, String, etc.

Comment: did you manage to use the protocol `ImmutableMappable` with nested objects?

Comment: I wrote an issue on github: https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/issues/749